# Convert MySQL query into JSON object using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, json, join

I am new to programming and have a question about converting a MYSQL query with a Join into a JSON object using PHP. When running the statement through phpMyAdmin I get results. However, when attempting the convert it into a JSON object I am getting a blank screen. Any help is greatly appreciated! Here is my code:

```
    $myquery = "SELECT track_ticseverity.date, track_ticseverity.ticnum, track_ticseverity.user_id, track_fatigue.date, track_fatigue.fatiguenum, track_fatigue.user_id 
    FROM track_ticseverity
          INNER JOIN track_fatigue
          ON track_ticseverity.date=track_fatigue.date
          WHERE track_ticseverity.user_id=1
          AND track_fatigue.user_id=1;"

    $query = mysqli_query($conn, $myquery);

   if ( ! $query ) {
       echo mysqli_error();
       die;
   }

   $data = array();

   for ($x = 0; $x < mysqli_num_rows($query); $x++) {
       $data[] = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);
   }

   echo json_encode($data);     

   mysqli_close($server);
```

Comment: What does the output of var_dump(json_encode($data)) show you?

Comment: Still nothing, should I replace a line I already have with that or just add it in?

Answer (score 0):

Did you connect to your database? (mysqli_connect)

It's not in your code example, but maybe you did anyway and didn't copy it.

If you did, to which variable did you assign the connection? Once you're using $conn in mysqli_query and once youre using $server in mysqli_close.

Maybe this is helping already even I think PHP should show errors in this case?

**Another Tipp**

You can easily write the following:

```
while($datarow = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query))  {
    $data[] = $datarow;
}
```

Like this, you can save the for-loop.

Comment: Yes I did connect to me database, I assigned it the variable on conn. When I use a simpler query without a join it works. For some reason the query I pasted above is not working.

Comment: As I can see, you found the mistake. PHP should print a Parse Error in this case. To make life easier for you, check if you disabled the error reporting somehow. PHP's error messages can be really useful to find mistakes quickly and get help by pasting them to google.

Answer (score 0):

I just figured it out. I ended my Query with ;" instead of ";
Thanks for your replies! Sorry I did not catch that before posting!

Comment: if you were getting nothing, not even a parse error from PHP; you'll want to consider turning error_reporting on.